# Wordpress get post content and upgrade a page

Tags: wordpress

I am stuck to upgrade my function.php in order to:

check if there is draft post

if there is get the content, title and category

if there is a page with title = post_category upgrade the content of the page 
with the post_content(and post_title)

else create a page with title = post_category and content = post_content and post_title

The code

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'privatepostcheck' );

function privatepostcheck(){

    $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'post_status' => 'draft'
              );
    // get the draft post         
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach($posts_array as $post){
        // foreach draft post get title, content and category
        $posttext = get_the_content($post);
        $postcate = get_the_category($post);
        $postitle = get_the_title($post);   

        //check if there is page with name = post category
        //get the page
        $page = get_page_by_title( $postcate );
        //get content
        $content_page = apply_filters('the_content', $page ->post_content);
        $content_post = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
        $page = array(
                'post_content' => "asidasoidjasoidjsaoi<br>".$content_page,
            );
        wp_update_post( $page );
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear where do you need this? Because `wp_insert_post()` function inserts a page or a post in a database. Do you want to output the drafted posts somewhere?

Comment: Hi dingo, I need to delete the draft, after the creation(or update) of a single page with the sum of the content